# creating new footer block in layout

Tags: layout, blocks

I am trying to create a new block for footer in `page.xml`

steps done are

`<block type="page/html_newfooter" name="newfooter" as="newfooter" template="page/html/newfooter.phtml">` added in page.xml

copied the `Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php` to 'local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/' and renamed to 'Newfooter.php' and renamed the class accordingly

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
```

remains untouched in page.xml

the idea is to call two footers in two different layouts

I am calling new footer like following getChildHtml('newfooter') ?> in my new layout

But its not working as expected . In both of my layouts either footer loads or newfooter loads irrespective of the layout i have selected for my pages.

<strike>I am refreshing cache every time. so that is not the issue</strike>

I think it is cache issue. After clearing cache if i load a page with footer then from there onwards all the pages will load footer. But if i load a page with newfooter then from there onwards all pages will load newfooter

I tried changing the `cache_tags` value in `_construct`
but not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

just override block

```
Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php
```

and in your

_construct function add condition

```
if()//

$this->setTemplate('page/html/footer.phtml')

else

$this->setTemplate('page/html/newfooter.phtml')
```

Comment: Will try this. since the template has been set from the layout will this work?

Comment: it will override the block param from layout.

Comment: What condition should i give inside if() condition?

Comment: it depends where u want to call the newfooter, say for a particular controller action, then put it as Mage::app()->getRequest(), 
->getControllerName();
->getActionName();

Comment: I have 2 layouts, eg layout 1 should load normal footer and layout 2 should load newfooter . is there a method to get the loaded layout name?

Comment: u can try $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles() which will give you all handles loaded for the page and then match it

Comment: I am not able to get the current template loaded neither from 'Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate()' nor using `$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()`.

Comment: I can make this work as expected by changing the cache key of the newfooter. But i don't know that is the right way. That's y i posted this question. Any i will stick with my way

Comment: that is definitely not the right way of coding in Magento!!!

Comment: i will try the code at my end..and give you a revised answer!